# Essential spectrum under perturbation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, compactness, perturbation-theory, spectral-radius

Given a Banach space $X$ and a bounded linear operator $T$ on $X$.
It's well known that the essential spectrum of $T$ is invariant under additive compact perturbation.

My question is about minimal hypotheses so that this result holds.

**$\star$** I am imagining a condition on the measure of non-compactness associated to the quotient norm.

Comment: There are at least 3 definitions of "essential spectrum" which are not equivalent (though the corresponding essential spectral radius is the same). Which definition do you mean?

Comment: The set of all complex numbers $\lambda$ such that $\lambda-T$ is not Fredholm operator. Since you've mentioned the essential radius, that's exactly what I am looking for: the stability of the essential radius under perturbation.

Answer (score 3):

A bounded operator $K$ on $X$ satisfies $T+K$ Fredholm for each $T$ Fredholm if and only if $K$ is inessential. See [P. Aiena, "Fredholm and Local Spectral Theory, with Applications to Multipliers". Kluwer, 2004.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/31607282_Fredholm_and_Local_Spectral_Theory_with_Applications_to_Multipliers)